# Clicking the Checkbox in the first column of the active row

Tags: java, selenium, select, checkbox, html-table

I am trying to click on a checkbox in a table. I search through the table and when I find the proper information in the 2nd column I want to click on the checkbox in the first column of that row

```
    public WebDriver searchSelectStore(WebDriver dr1, String srchTable, String srchFor) {
 // Grab the table 
    WebElement table = dr1.findElement(By.id(srchTable)); 

    // Now get all the TR elements from the table 
    List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); 

    // And iterate over them, getting the cells 
    for (WebElement row : allRows) { 
        List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td")); 

    for (WebElement cell : cells) { 
        // 

         if(cell.getText().equals(srchFor)){ 


              System.out.println(row.getText());

                   // here I need to click on the first column of that row



             }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd actually rewrite your code a little, since you say that you're always checking the second cell for the text and then when found, clicking on the first I'd do something like this:

```
List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));  
for (WebElement row : allRows) {
    if (row.findElement(By.xpath("./td[2]").getText().equals(srchFor)){
        row.findElement(By.xpath("./td[1]").click();
    }
}
```